# Threading & SpiDev - IOError [Errno 9]: Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, multithreading, spi, ioerror

I've created a function for threading which continuously checks a chip register for an interrupt and if this interrupt occurs it'll get values from the chip, do some calculation and put the calculated values in a queue which is linked to a GUI created with tkinter.

```
def workerThread1(self):
    ##registers##
    AWATTHR = 0x01
    [...]

    ##variables##
    cAWATTHR = 2.365579 * 10 ** (-5)
    [...]

    ##register values##
    b1MMODE = 0xFC
    [...]

    ##set up SPI##
    spi = spidev.SpiDev()
    spi.open(0, 0)
    spi.mode=0b01

    ##write register values##
    spi.xfer2([WRITE|MMODE, b1MMODE], SPISPD, SPIDLY, SPILNG)
    [...]

    ##loop##
    spi.xfer2([WRITE|LINECYC, b1LINECYC, b2LINECYC], SPISPD, SPIDLY, SPILNG)
    spi.xfer2([RSTATUS], SPISPD, SPIDLY, SPILNG)
    while self.running == 1:
        n = n + 1
        rFREQ = spi.xfer2([FREQ, DBYTE, DBYTE], SPISPD, SPIDLY, SPILNG)
        vFREQ = Bits(uint = rFREQ[1]*VMSB16BIT + rFREQ[2], length = 16)
        sFREQ = sFREQ + vFREQ.uint
        LENERGY = [...]
        if LENERGY == '1':
            rvFREQ = (1 / ((sFREQ / n) * 9.6 * 10 ** (-6)))
            [...]
            transfer = [rvFREQ, [...]]
            self.queue.put(transfer)                
            n = 0
            sFREQ = 0
    spi.close()
```

Unfortunately I always get "IOError: (Errno 9) Bad file descriptor" with the following Traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/pi/GUI-LOG/GUI1.py", line 277, in workerThread1
rFREQ = spi.xfer2([FREQ, DBYTE, DBYTE], SPISPD, SPIDLY, SPILNG)
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I'm looking forward to any hints about what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Looks like opening the spi device is failing.  Check the status on your spi object prior to reading or writing with it.

Comment: Hi Andy, I've checked that with an logic analyzer. SPI is opened and I can see all the communication (12 writes) and the read which is meant to be stored in rFREQ for further processing. The device is currently not connected, so rFREQ should be [0x00, 0x00, 0x00] but due to the IOError, nothing is stored in rFREQ.

Comment: Is this ran simultaneously in more than one thread?  If so, it could be that the underlying xfer2 routine itself is not thread safe in which case you'll need to mutex the writes.

Comment: @Andy I have the same issue in an interrupt which writes/reads via SPI which in some cases also can happen simultaneously. I tried to mutex the write and read funtion of the SPI but that error still happened. Any other Ideas? mths did you figured it out?

Comment: If your open/close is not executed as pair, for example open time is greater than close time, the exception will occur.